# Proving Simple Exponential Dominance Fact

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to prove this simple and very believable exponential dominance fact:

> Given $\lambda_{0}\in\left(0,1\right)$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, for
>   $\lambda_{1}\in\left(\lambda_{0},1\right)$ there exists a constant $K$
>   so that $$k\lambda_{0}^{k}\le K\lambda_{1}^{k}.$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it that $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$ are fixed, and that you want $K$ independant of $k$ ? If yes, use the fact that the sequence $u_k=k(\lambda_0/\lambda_1)^k$ has limit $0$ if $k\to +\infty$.

Comment: Yes this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$k \lambda_0^k<K\lambda_1^k$$
$$k\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}\right)^k<K$$
Since $\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}=a$ is less than 1, the left-hand side attains a maximum value when $k>0$ of $\frac1{e\ln\frac1a}=\frac1{e\ln\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_0}}$. We may thus choose $K$ as any number greater than this last expression if $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$ are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $$u_{k}=k\left(\frac{\lambda_{0}}{\lambda_{1}}\right)^{k}.$$
  Then $u_{k}\to0$
  as $k\to\infty.$
  Fix $K$
  so that $u_{k}\le1$
  for $k\ge K$
 . Then for $k\le K$
  we have $$k\lambda_{0}^{k}\le K\lambda_{1}^{k}$$
  and for $k\ge K$
  we have $$k\lambda_{0}^{k}\le\lambda_{1}^{k}\le K\lambda_{1}^{k}.$$